# getting warning message while upgrading numpy

Tags: python, numpy, warnings, upgrade, message

When I tried to update numpy in jupyter notebook I got this warning: **WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (c:\users\rog strix\appdata\roaming\python\python310\site-packages)** what this warning message means and how to avoid this warning message. I couldn't locate this path also. what is meant by rotobuf.

how to avoid such warning

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)